# Win odds displayed in the Big Game S2 E17

Tags: odds, hand

Look at [this spot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5UV7hDsB7y8#t=37m55s) of the Big Game, season 2, episode 17.

Elky holds K♠️ J♠️ and Minieri holds A♦️K♣️. On the flop of 6♣️ 3♠️ 2♠️ the winning percentage of 55% for Elky and 45% for Minieri is shown. I wonder if these numbers can be correct. There are 9 outs for Elky, A♠️ Q♠️ T♠️ 9♠️ 8♠️ 7♠️ 6♠️ 5♠️ 4♠️, and three more J♥️ J♦️ J♣️ where Minieri has a redraw. So I feel the winning percentage for Elky should be more like 45%.

Answer (score 1):

While typing the question I think I found the answer on my own. Watching the preceding action reveals that the other players have folded the cards K♥️ Q♦️ T♦️ 9♦️ 6♦️ T♣️ 8♣️ 4♣️, not containing any out of Elky. That improves his chances and 55% might make sense then.

Answer (score 1):

Azimut's speculation is correct.  For a bit more detail:

There are 15 cards from the hole cards and flop that are unavailable, leaving 37 possible remaining cards for 666 possible turn/river combinations.

For the most part Minieri wins if neither card is a jack or a spade.  Such cards number 25 remaining.  25 choose 2 yields 300 matching combinations.

The only complications here are that 6 of those 300 combinations are a split pot (where a non-spade 4/5 hits and both players have the board straight).  And Minieri has an additional 6 winning combinations for him when a non-spade A hits with a J.

| Winner | combinations | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Elky | 360 | 54% |
| Minieri | 300 | 45% |
| Split | 6 | 1% |